# Invalid Cast Exception on Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a new Xamarin.Forms mobile app and the only thing I did was replace the default welcome to xamarin label in the `.xaml` file with:

```
    <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Label Text="You are: (X)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"/>
    <Label Text="Your opponent is: (O)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
    </Grid>
```

The previewer doesn't work on either android or ios preview, and when I run the program I get a `System.InvalidCastException` on this line of code, that is already in the pregenerated code: `global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(ticTactTestPage));`

I'm still a beginner so I did some goole searching on this, and most of the time the exception is thrown in code written by the developer, however in this case I haven't touched anything except deleting `<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin!"/>` from the `.xaml` file. Can anyone help solve this?

Edit 1: A user suggested moving the labels inside of the `<Grid><Grid/>` since I originally had them outside. However, the issue still remains.

Comment: from a very brief look at your code, it looks like your labels are outside of the <Grid></Grid>, which might be the cause of your problem

Comment: @Ale_lipa thanks for the response, I changed the code so that the labels are inside and had no luck. same result. I'm gonna update the question so nobody else offers that solution. thanks again.

Comment: Another thing is that there's something wrong with your ColumnDefinitions (e.g. ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>>). Remove the second closing bracket '>'

Comment: Remove the extra > from the column definitions <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>>

Comment: The code now runs, and I'm a fool lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `>` at the end of your ColumnDefinition Widths elements:

```
<Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
<Label Text="You are: (X)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"/>
<Label Text="Your opponent is: (O)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
```

#### XAML Compilation

To catch most of these types of typos in XAML, you can enable the XAML compiler (`XAMLC`).

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

> XAMLC offers a number of a benefits:

- It performs compile-time checking of XAML, notifying the user of any errors.
- It removes some of the load and instantiation time for XAML elements.
- It helps to reduce the file size of the final assembly by no longer including .xaml files.

#### Assembly level:

```
~~~~
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace PhotoApp
~~~~
```

#### Class level:

```
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public class HomePage : ContentPage
{
  ~~~
```

Comment: @MatthewKaminski You should enable the XAMLC to catch these types of errors at compile time... ;-)